# How do I implement HTTP headers into my website?

Tags: .htaccess, security, http-headers

I audited my website on a vulnerability checker and it suggested that I need to add security headers;

> Missing security header for XSS Protection.
>
> Missing security header to prevent Content Type sniffing.
>
> Missing Strict-Transport-Security security header.
>
> Leaked PHP version. Your site is displaying your PHP version in the
>   HTTP headers on https://www.mywebsite.com/blog/. Please set
>   expose_php = Off.

I went to my htaccess file and tried adding some of the headers that [this site](https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/http-security-headers/) recommends, here's what I've tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The above works for everything except my /blog subdomain, which incidently is hosted on a CMS.

When I add the header below, my site instantly stops working.

```
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age= Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=; 
includeSubDomains Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=; preload
```

Im totally inexperienced in this area, and want to remove all of the vulnerabilities that the auditing website found.

Comment: Can someone upvote this post please i still need help. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this code to my htaccess file and re scanned the website and the issues were resolved.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" //help protect against XSS
Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN //help protect against page-framing and clickjacking
Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff //help protect against content-sniffin
Header add Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31415926;includeSubDomains;"//I believe this adds https before the domain on all pages.

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_flag expose_php off //This stop divulging the php version
</IfModule>
```

Go [here](https://htaccessbook.com/increase-security-x-security-headers/) for more concise details.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add this to your **header** site:

**Missing security header for XSS Protection:** X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

**Missing security header to prevent Content Type sniffing**: X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

**Missing Strict-Transport-Security security header**: max-age=31536000;includeSubDomains; preload

Rescan/Retest and the vulnerabilities will be fixed.

Some intereresting websites that gives you a nice and profound perspective from your website:

- [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/)
- [HSTS PreLoad](https://hstspreload.org/)

Comment: Thankyou. also worth noting that one needs to wrap those tags in the <IfModule> tag